# Handling borders when applying a filter to an image

Tags: java, arrays, image, image-processing, convolution

I'm trying to tidy up some of my github projects for a portfolio and was hoping for some help.

I have a basic image convolution kernel program in java to apply a filter to an input image.
The kernels are 3x3 and 5x5 2D arrays and are applied across each pixel in the image. Obviously this causes issues around the edges where 3-5 cells in the kernels will be multiplied against empty values (causing the outer pixels in the image to be black or white)

Below are some examples of what I mean (the white pixel bar, not the grey part)

[image: this is an example of the pixel line across the lefthand side of the image]

[image: This is an example of the pixel line across the top]

The following is the crux of the code involving the image processing.

```
for (int xCoord = 0; xCoord < (width); xCoord++) { // -2
        for (int yCoord = 0; yCoord < (height); yCoord++) {

            // Output Red, Green and Blue Values
            int outR, outG, outB, outA;

            // Temp red, green, blue values that will contain the total r/g/b values after
            // kernel multiplication
            double red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0;
            int outRGB = 0;

            /*
             * Loop over the Kernel (For each cell in kernel)
                The offset is added to the xCoord and yCoord to follow the footprint of the
                kernel
                The logic behind below is that all kernels are uneven numbers (so they can
                have a centre pixel, 3x3 5x5 etc),
                the offset needs to run from negative half their length (rounded down) to the
                positive of half their length (rounded down)
                This allows us to input kernels of various sizes (5x5, 9x9 etc) and the
                calculation should not be thrown off
             */
            try {
                for (int xOffset = Math.negateExact(k.getKernels().length / 2); xOffset <= k.getKernels().length
                        / 2; xOffset++) {
                    for (int yOffset = Math.negateExact(k.getKernels().length / 2); yOffset <= k.getKernels().length
                            / 2; yOffset++) {
```

The first 2 loops iterate over each pixel. The second 2 loops are looping over the kernel (A 2D array enum class) The offset is used to loop across the 3x3 or 5x5 kernel at each pixel in the image.

Follows is my very basic attempt to wrap the pixels sampled so edge pixels will use values at the opposite side of the image but my main question is how would be best to handle these edge cases. If anyone has any pointers of where to start solving this it would be much appreciated.

```
// TODO //very basic wrapping logic
                        int realX = (xCoord - k.getKernels().length / 2 + xOffset + width) % width;
                        int realY = (yCoord - k.getKernels().length / 2 + yOffset + height) % height;

                        int RGB = image.getRGB((realX), (realY)); // The RGB value for the pixel, will be split out
                                                                    // below
                        int A = (RGB >> 24) & 0xFF; // Bitshift 24 to get alpha value
                        int R = (RGB >> 16) & 0xFF; // Bitshift 16 to get Red Value
                        int G = (RGB >> 8) & 0xFF; // Bit Shift 8 to get Green Value
                        int B = (RGB) & 0xFF;

                        // actual rgb * kernel logic
                        red += (R * (k.getKernels()[yOffset + k.getKernels().length / 2])[xOffset
                                + k.getKernels().length / 2] * multiFactor);
                        green += (G * k.getKernels()[yOffset + k.getKernels().length / 2][xOffset
                                + k.getKernels().length / 2] * multiFactor);
                        blue += (B * k.getKernels()[yOffset + k.getKernels().length / 2][xOffset
                                + k.getKernels().length / 2] * multiFactor);
                        alpha += (A * k.getKernels()[yOffset + k.getKernels().length / 2][xOffset
                                + k.getKernels().length / 2] * multiFactor);

                    }
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

            // Logic here prevents pixel going over 255 or under 0
            // The "winner"of the max between the Colour value or 0(min pixel value) will be
            // Math.min with 255 (the max value for a pixel)
            outR = (int) Math.min(Math.max((red + bias), 0), 255);
            outG = (int) Math.min(Math.max((green + bias), 0), 255);
            outB = (int) Math.min(Math.max((blue + bias), 0), 255);
            outA = (int) Math.min(Math.max((alpha + bias), 0), 255);

            // Reassembling the separate color channels into one variable again.
            outRGB = outRGB | (outA << 24);
            outRGB = outRGB | (outR << 16);
            outRGB = outRGB | (outG << 8);
            outRGB = outRGB | outB;

            // Setting with the reassembled RGB value
            // output.setRGB(xCoord, yCoord, outRGB);
```

I'm a bit stumped how to proceed but if anyone can suggest efficient ways to handle these edge cases or even point me in the right direction or even some constructive criticism for how to improve any of the code. If anyone's interested the full project is [here](https://github.com/Timmyctc/ImageProcessing)

Comment: As a suggestion, you could either reduce the size of the output image to compensate or scale the "good part" of the image up to remove the edges - but I hope there is a better solution

Comment: lots of options https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5 there is no "good" solution, the choice depends on the situation. `replicate` or `reflect` might be the most useful on average.

Comment: Thanks guys gives me a good start for moving forward